# Как нагрузить поле логина для login.microsoftonline.com с помощью Jmeter?

Tags: юнит-тесты, cookie, jmeter

Мне нужно нагрузить одну аппку, вход в которою осуществляется через login.microsoftonline.com, но я получаю такую ошибку:

> "We can`t sign you injmeter your browser is currently set to block cookies. you need to allow cookies to use this service.

Я пробовал менять тип HTTP Cookie Manager с standart на другие, также я использовал CookieManager.save.cookies с значением true и false, но ничего не помогло.

[image: запрос]

[image: HTTP Cookie Manager]

[image: Ответ на запрос]

Answer (score 0):

Я сомневаюсь что запрос на `login.microsoftonline.com` должен быть первым в вашем тесте, скорее всего сначала вы должны открыть страницу своего приложения, там вы получите все нужные [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) и потом, когда вы выполните запрос на логин вас должно [перенаправить](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) на страницу login.microsoftonline.com с готовым адресом для [аутентификации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols)

Скорее всего вам придется вытащить несколько динамических параметров типа flowToken, client-request-id, и так далее, это можно сделать через [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), процесс называется [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) и в сети очень много информации на эту тему

Comment: Я использую эту ссылку потому-что я не могу показать настоящую, из-за NDA. Но там результат такой же. И да меня перенаправляет на loginmicrosoft

Comment: Я использую корреляцию, но из-за этой ошибки не могу екстрактить нужные мне параметры. Так как они отсутствуют.